# TPU VM ssh connect unstable or disconnect after some seconds

Tags: ssh, disconnect, google-cloud-tpu

When I use the command `proxychains gcloud alpha compute tpus tpu-vm ssh xx  --zone zone` to connect TPU VM, the connection only lasts 5 to 10 seconds.

This is very bad because I don't have time to get it to execute my command.
I have checked the firewall rules, and also try the command `gcloud compute config-ssh`.
And I have tried to restart my TPU VM and `sshd`. None of these methods worked for me.
Has anyone else encountered such a problem? Very much asking for your help.

Comment: Please provide some more details to reproduce & debug the problem. The information mentioned is not enough for reproducing it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have resolved the problem by config the proxy for the `gcloud` command.